# Cakephp Model ignoring database settings

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

**Update: please see my EDIT section below where I explain what I have discovered after testing**

I'm working on a website with CakePHP 2.5.1, and I'm experiencing a very strange behavior: **one** of the 2 models I have *seems* to refuse to use a different database configuration (other than the default one) if I don't place it in Cake's default **Model** folder (if I place it there everything works great).

Both models are located in the same folder, which happens to be **not the default Model folder** (this is because those are shared with other websites and I have a central place where I put all the shared ones).

To make Cake find those models I use the following line of code in the **bootstrap.php** file: `App::build(array('Model' => array(dirname(ROOT) . DS . '_shared/Cake_v2/Model')));`

The 2 models I have there are called *Campanya* and *EjercicioMultChoice*.

Everything seems to be setup properly:

- If I print `App::objects('Model')` I can see both models listed there, which means Cake is finding them in that external folder
- If I print `get_class_vars('DATABASE_CONFIG')` I can see both database configurations: the **default** one, used by *Campanya*, and the **custom** one (called **BD_Contenidos**), used by *EjercicioMultChoice*.
- Both models are included in the **AppController.php** with the `$uses` variable array.

I can call the *Campanya* model in the controller without any problem. However, when call the *EjercicioMultChoice* model, I get the following error:

```
MISSING DATABASE TABLE
Error: Table ejercicio_mult_choices for model EjercicioMultChoice was not found in datasource default.
```

This is how the *EjercicioMultChoice* model file looks like:

```
class EjercicioMultChoice extends AppModel {

public $name = 'EjercicioMultChoice';
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $useTable = 'ejercicios_multiple_choice';
public $useDbConfig = 'BD_Contenidos'; 
}
```

As you can see, that model indicates to use a specific database configuration, which Cake is aware of, but in the error shown above it's saying that it can't find the table in datasource **default**. It can't because it's not there of course, it's in another table in another database (which by the way this other database is in the same server as the default one and I use it without issues on other projects).

As I mention above, if I move that exact same *EjercicioMultChoice.php* model file to Cake's default **app/Model/** folder, then I don't have any issues.

So I'm a bit lost here, I don't know what else I can check to find what the issue is.

**EDIT**

So I believe I've discovered what the problem is, and a workaround about it, but I still would like to know why this is happening and how can I make it work as it should.

If I add these 2 lines of code (**both of them**) before calling the model then it all works fine:

```
$this->EjercicioMultChoice->setDataSource('BD_Contenidos');
$this->EjercicioMultChoice->setSource('ejercicios_multiple_choice');
```

This clearly means that even though Cake finds the *EjercicioMultChoice.php* model file, which indicates the database and table names, it ignores those 2 variables (**$useTable** and **$useDbConfig**). The only way to make it work is by manually setting those 2 variables with the methods that I wrote above.

Why is this happening? This does not happen if the model file is in the default folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well well, it seems that the problem was that I didn't put the trailing `/` in the **App::build()** path. The correct one should be `App::build(array('Model' => array(dirname(ROOT) . DS . '_shared/Cake_v2/Model/')));`

What made it hard for me to figure this out is that Cake was actually finding the models in that folder, even without the trailing `/`, but for some reason that prevented it from loading the internal contents of those model files.

Anyway, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, cake is NOT loading your provided model file!
You can find out by putting an `exit();` call in the first line of that (shared) file and see if your app honors that (by showing a white page ,-)).

If not, your model file does not get picked up by cakephp.

Another way to check if your model file gets picked up is to define a custom member variable like `public $myModelTestVar = 'sharedModel';` to the file and just check for the variable in the controller that uses the model (just `debug($this->EjercicioMultChoice)` in an action).

If you can confirm/proove that the file is picked up, I would volunteer to set this scenario up and try myself whats going on there - but am very certain I am right.

```
debug(dirname(ROOT) . DS . '_shared/Cake_v2/Model')
```

to proove it's pointing to where you expect.

Comment: thank you for your help, it was something like that (see my answer where I explain what was going on)